# Amadeus City and Airports Location API AutoComplete System

Tags: javascript, search, fetch, amadeus, city

I am adding the AutoComplete System to a booking website that I am developing. I understand that the autoComplete system fetches from a pre-populated data.So I am trying to locations/airport codes from
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations to view the list of all locations so that I can design the auto-complete system but I get a bad response, my application is missing an important parameter.I am trying to display a list of locations.
I hope someone can point out where I have gone wrong.

```
"use_strict";
function getLocations(){
 let url = "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations";  
 fetch(url,{
     method:"GET",
     headers:{
         "Content-Type":"application/json",
         "Authorization":"Bearer BgRWNa48WGmqPowlRCMvIwHt6a96"
     },
     mode:"cors",
     catch:"default"
 }).then(function(response){
         return response.json();
 }).then(function(data){
     console.log(data);
 }).catch(function(error){
     console.log(error);
 });
}

getLocations();
```

**

> : Object { status: 400, code: 32171, title: "MANDATORY DATA MISSING",
> … }

**
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the mandatory query parameters. According to the [API reference](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search/api-reference), `subType` (AIRPORT or CITY) and `keyword` parameters are needed. For example:

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations?subType=AIRPORT&keyword=LON
```

will return a list of airports whose name contains the keyword `LON` (London Heathrow, London Gatwick, London Stansted, etc.)

Comment: I'm trying to create autocomplete search on my booking website using JavaScript. I want users to type in  city name in a search field that will send a request to Amadeus Locations to auto-suggest the location the user is trying to write. @alnacle

Comment: So  what I want is that I don't need to add a city or airport name. I want users to write the city/airport of current location and destination in the search form. If you can give the link to the Amadeus City/Airport AutoComplete script in Pure JavaScript or JQuery, I will be happy@alnacle

Comment: Check this out: 

https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/airport-autocomplete-jquery-ajax

Hopefully it will help you :)